# Why are my deleted messages in my delete folder deleting after three days?

Tags: outlook.com

I delete messages and if I do not want them I go in and permanently delete them.  I have noticed for the last month when I delete a message and then go to my delete folder after three days it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

OutLook has an ***Automatic Junk Delete AI***, with a feature to disable it just like gmail except it has a 3 month garente that junk won't be deleted until the period of 24 hours of the last day 90 days after the message went into the junk folder...

For more info on how to disable it go to http://sites.psu.edu/maitshelp/2012/07/12/how-do-i-turn-off-auto-delete-in-outlook/